# Problema con ownershipRelationship para mostrar registros en FilamentPHP

Tags: php, laravel, lumen, filamentphp, tenant

tengo un modelo donde administro todos los permisos del sistema pero no puedo mostrar todos los registros, en el caso de este modelo no es necesario que pertenezca a un inquilino o haya una relación de propiedad, sin embargo la configuración requiere que tenga un propietario ¿Cómo puedo evitar esto?

Tenia mi modelo asi:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Filament\Panel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

class Permission extends Model 
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
    ];

    public function users(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }

    public function owner(): HasMany
    {
        //return $this->hasMany(Permission::class, 'id');
        return $this->hasMany(Permission::class, 'id')->where('id', '<>', 0);
    }
}
```

Luego intente esto:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Filament\Facades\Filament;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany;

class Permission extends Model 
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
    ];

    public function users(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }

    public function owner()
    {
        //Filament::getTenant()->id;
        //return $this->hasMany(Permission::class, 'id');
        $permissions = Permission::where('id', '>=', 1)->get();
        //dd($permissions);
        return $permissions;
        //return $this->hasMany(Permission::class, 'id')->where('id', '>=', Filament::getTenant()->id);
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y tengo configurado mi panel de Filamentphp de esta forma

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers\Filament;

use App\Models\Company;
use Filament\Http\Middleware\Authenticate;
use Filament\Http\Middleware\DisableBladeIconComponents;
use Filament\Http\Middleware\DispatchServingFilamentEvent;
use Filament\Pages;
use Filament\Panel;
use Filament\PanelProvider;
use Filament\Support\Colors\Color;
use Filament\Widgets;
use Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse;
use Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken;
use Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings;
use Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession;
use Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession;
use Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession;

class CompanyPanelProvider extends PanelProvider
{
    public function panel(Panel $panel): Panel
    {
        return $panel
            ->id('company')
            ->path('gym')
            ->colors([
                'danger' => Color::rgb('rgb(255,0,0)'),
                'gray' => Color::Gray,
                'info' => Color::Green,
                'primary' => Color::Violet,
                'success' => Color::Lime,
                'warning' => Color::rgb('rgb(255,69,0)'),
                'edit' => Color::Blue,
            ])
            //->spa()
            ->authGuard('company')
            ->profile()
            ->login()
            ->passwordReset()
            ->authPasswordBroker('companies')
            ->maxContentWidth('full')
            ->sidebarCollapsibleOnDesktop()
            ->discoverResources(in: app_path('Filament/Company/Resources'), for: 'App\\Filament\\Company\\Resources')
            ->discoverPages(in: app_path('Filament/Company/Pages'), for: 'App\\Filament\\Company\\Pages')
            ->pages([
                Pages\Dashboard::class,
            ])
            ->discoverWidgets(in: app_path('Filament/Company/Widgets'), for: 'App\\Filament\\Company\\Widgets')
            ->widgets([
                //
            ])
            ->middleware([
                EncryptCookies::class,
                AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
                StartSession::class,
                AuthenticateSession::class,
                ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
                VerifyCsrfToken::class,
                SubstituteBindings::class,
                DisableBladeIconComponents::class,
                DispatchServingFilamentEvent::class,
            ])
            ->authMiddleware([
                Authenticate::class,
            ])
            ->tenant(Company::class, slugAttribute: 'slug', ownershipRelationship: 'owner');
    }
}
```

Cabe mencionar que el sistema que estoy desarrollando es un saas donde utilizo tenant, pero para este caso no necesito el ownershipRelationship, ya que quiero listar todos los permisos del sistema sin importar esta parte... No se si se entiende a lo que voy, entonces de que forma hago esto?

Comment: y el error cual es? sale algo por pantalla?